# Golang google storage resumable upload HTTP 401

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

Hey im trying to implement  a resumable upload to cloud storage .

But im getting a    **Status:"401 Unauthorized", StatusCode:401**

And im assuming  that it`s something with the bearer but i can't figure out  another way to send the bearer Token.

I've been able to delete files with the GetClinet method.

```
func GetClinet(c endpoints.Context) *http.Client {
    cli := &http.Client{
        Transport: &oauth2.Transport{
            Source: google.AppEngineTokenSource(c, storage.ScopeReadWrite),
            Base:   &urlfetch.Transport{Context: c},
        },
    }

    return cli

}

client := GetClinet(con)

url := "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketName/file.txt"
b := r.Header.Get("Authorization") //parse the bearer from user request
r, err = http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)
r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain")
r.Header.Add("Content-Length", "0")
r.Header.Add("x-goog-resumable", "start")
r.Header.Add("Authorization", b)

resp, err := client.Do(r)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if "parse the bearer from the user request" implies that you are running a web server and that you want to access the user's Google Cloud Storage account. If so, you may want to familiarize yourself with: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: @rein learning curve is high just for that token, documentation is not good enough in this case, code in the other hand is more usefull https://github.com/johnbalvin/google-cloud-go/blob/master/storage/resumableUpload.go

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar difficulties, not sure if your situation is the same as mine. My goal is to

1. User client uploads meta-data to my server
2. Server authenticates and stores in DB
3. Server asks Google Cloud Storage for `resumabale upload url`
4. Server returns url to client
5. Client uses url to upload media to GCS

I'm getting 401 unauthorized returns too. Maybe I'm not setting the headers correctly? or the `storage.SignedURL` doesn't handle resumable uploads properly...?

I've been able to upload files using a Service Account PEM file

```
func setGcsFile(c context.Context, fileId string, content []byte) error {
    expiration := time.Now().Add(time.Second * 30) //expire in 30 seconds

    data, err = ioutil.ReadFile(serviceAccountPEMFilename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Debugf(c, "Getting upload url")
    opts := &storage.SignedURLOptions{
        GoogleAccessID: googleAccessID,
        PrivateKey:     data,
        Method:         "PUT",
        Expires:        expiration,
    }

    putURL, err := storage.SignedURL(bucket, fileId, opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Debugf(c, "%v", err)
        return err
    }

    log.Debugf(c, "PUT URL : %v\n", putURL)

    client := urlfetch.Client(c)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", putURL, bytes.NewBuffer(content))
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Debugf(c, "%v", err)
        return err
    }
    res.Body.Close()
    log.Debugf(c, "Response Code: %s\n", res.Status)
    return nil
}
```

I'm thinking about pulling and modifying the `storage.SignedURL` function next.